Unable to pass a variable to another function in python
I'm building a Flask app that captures and records videos using OpenCV. I've split my code into multiple files for better organization, but I'm having trouble accessing a global variable (user_data, which stores the recording path) in my generate_frames function, which is defined in a separate module (camera.py).
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, jsonify
from camera import *
import threading

# ... other imports and functions ...

user_data = None
video_thread = None

# ... other routes ...

@app.route('/save_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    global user_data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        g.user_data = name
        print(f"Recording path updated to: {g.user_data}")
        return f"System will now record and store the data as per the destination you selected, {name}."
    return render_template('index.html', system_info=get_system_info(), user_data=user_data)

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


from flask import *

# ... other imports and functions ...
def generate_frames():
    # ... video capture and processing logic ...

    user_data = g.user_data
    print(f"User data in generate_frames: {user_data}")

    # ... (use user_data for recording) ...


The issue stems from the fact that when you import camera.py into app.py, the code in camera.py is executed and creates its own copy of the user_data variable. Even though you modify the global user_data in app.py, this change isn't reflected in camera.py's version of the variable.
Even though I update user_data in the /save_file route, when generate_frames runs, it still sees the initial value of user_data (which is None). I understand that this is likely a scoping issue because the modules are imported and executed separately.
I've tried using the global keyword in both files, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I correctly access the updated user_data value in the generate_frames function?
any help would be helpfull... I m trying this to figure out from very long now....

If you want to change it in the camera module, then you need to import camera, then access it via camera.user_data.  If you do from camera import * or from camera import user_data, then you're creating a new variable in your own namespace, so assigning to it won't affect the copy in the camera module.

Oh I get it , this must be because it is creating a local copy of variable, Thanks, I tried figuring out for so long but now I know thank you very much.

Yeah, it's not immediately obvious that it works that way, but once you understand it, it's pretty simple.

Flask has a dedicated feature for this https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/#storing-data
